# linux: per-process monitor, every 10 minutes, with history access

Tags: linux, memory, cpu-usage, virtual-memory, process

I really didn't know a better way to ask my question, hence you get a horribly named question.

I will explain what i want to do, maybe that will help you help me.

I would like to have my linux machine continuously monitor (every 10 minutes) all the processes on my machine. The information from each process that I require is the name, CPU usage, allocated (virtual) memory, and resident (ram) memory.

If these periodic reports were to be looked at, they would look something like this:

```
PROCESS    CPU    RAM    VIRTUAL
name1    %    MB    MB
name2    %    MB    MB
...etc..etc
```

These reports should be stored in such a way that I can access them at a later date by giving a date/time scope (range). For instance, if I want to see the history of my processes from 12:00:00 1.12.12 till 12:00:00 2.12.12 I can - and it should give me the history of the processes for every 10 minutes between those date/time borders.

The format of the return is not important, that will be handled by a script anyway and can be modified into anything I need.

I have looked into a few things so far, but have not found something that clearly meets my needs. Among the things i searched: [sar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sar), [free(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?free%201), [top(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?top%201).. and a few other things.

It should be a simple issue, i can already see all this information by simply looking at my `htop`, but i need only a tool that will gather the desired fields for me for each processes every 10 minutes, and then also let me extract slices of that data based on date/time scopes (ranges).

note: I have limited experience with linux, so please give detailed information.

note2: The desired output will be something like this (after receiving the desired range)

```
CPU USAGE BY PROCESS:
proc_nameA 1,2,2,2,2,2...... numbers represent % usage every 10 minutes...
proc_nameB 4,3,3,6,1,2......
```

The same idea with the other information.

Comment: I believe collectd can do what you want. http://collectd.org/ It'll produce rrdtool files, which you can graph however.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `atop`.

It will log all of these system information for every 5 or 10 minutes (depending on what your distribution has chosen for you) as a daemon and put that in binary files. Then use

```
atop -r
```

To view the contents of today's standard logfile interactively. It's like `htop` with some extra I/O info which allows you to go back in time and see what happened on those moments. Press <kbd>t</kbd> to go forward and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to go back.

You can also point it to a specific time range. From the manpage:

```
With the flag -b (begin time) and/or -e (end time) followed by a time argument
of the form HH:MM, a certain time period within the raw file can be selected.
```

It's just not overly configurable on what to write in the raw files.

I suggest you to read more of the manpage of atop as well to get started, e.g. reading the contents of yesterday's logfile.

*Here's how my machine 'zarafa' was performing this morning between 7:35:40 and 7:45:40:*

[image: atop screenshot]

Comment: Looks like a good start - but can this support the type of access I require? via - date/time scope (range) access? if not, will it have the date/time of the specific entry so I can do my own parsing? For how long does it keep old information? Can I decide what information it collects?

Comment: @InbarRose That's just RTFM imo as I already pointed out in my answer. I suggest to ask a more specific question if you can't get it to do what you want.